# How information from future can save someone's life?

Tags: time-travel

In the imagined future, robots rised against humans and rapidly begun to win the humankind. One of the genius inventors invented a time machine. That time machine could not move a matter in time. It could only change the state of particles (i. e. electrons).

So, the inventor contacted himself in the past using that time machine and instant messenger that he used in the past. (He modified the bits in memory of messaging servers.) He managed to do this just few minutes before robots capture his office and kill him.

What could the inventor tell himself in the past in order to save his life?

Comment: Watch Stein's Gate. It's a 26 episode show about pretty much what you just asked.

Comment: Have a look at the link in the close reason to see why we've closed. There is the core of a good question here but it needs to be much more constrained and have a way to rate the answers.

Comment: As the question stands, he could send himself the complete history of the rise of the machines as a pdf document, complete with pictures. It wouldn't have to be a very big file. It would have important dates, names of people instrumental to the beginning of the history of the rise of the machines, critical points where things went one way and not another, weaknesses to exploit, and what-if scenarios from analysts on how it could have been prevented at each step. Hindsight is 20/20.